# how to convert optional parameter method to delegate in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a casting problem.

```
public void Test(int a = 0) { }

System.Action d = Test;
```

this code works well in unity 5.

but visual studio 2015 can't compile it.

> CS0123    No overload for 'Test' matches delegate 'Action'

why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised it works in Unity - it shouldn't. That sounds like a Mono compiler bug.

The C# 5 specification isn't as clear on this as it should be, but from the draft of the upcoming ECMA C# 5 standard, from the clause on method group conversions - emphasis mine:

> - A single method M is selected corresponding to a method invocation of the form `E(A)`, with the following modifications:
>
>   - The argument list `A` is a list of expressions, each classified as a variable and with the type and modifier (`ref` or `out`) of the corresponding parameter in the *formal-parameter-list* of `D` – excepting parameters of type `dynamic`, where the corresponding expression has the type `object` instead of `dynamic`.
>   - The candidate methods considered are only those methods that are applicable in their normal form **and do not omit any optional parameters**. Thus, candidate methods are ignored if they are applicable only in their expanded form, or if one or more of their optional parameters do not have a corresponding parameter in `D`.

The simplest fix is to use a lambda expression, as Dai says:

```
Action d = () => Test();
```

Comment: Senpai noticed me!

Answer (score 6):

When a method with optional parameters is invoked, it actually is compiled as a call *with* argument values for those parameters, with those values determined by the method's declared defaults.

If you have a method declared and used like this:

```
public void Foo(String x = "foo", Int32 y = 123) {
    // do something
}

public void Bar() {
    Foo();
}
```

Then compile this, and look at the generated CIL in the assembly you'll see that `Bar` is actually doing this: (as opposed to the compiler doing some voodoo with the compiled CIL and calling-conventions, e.g. C-style variadic functions)

```
public void Bar() {
    Foo("foo", 123);
}
```

(This also explains why default values must be compile-time constants (because they're essentially placed verbatim in the calling code), and you should note that if you change the value of an optional parameter's default value in one assembly without recompiling the calling assembly then the old value will continue to be used (just like `public const` is).)

My point is that a method with optional parameters is still **formally** a multi-parameter method, which is why a delegate with a subset of parameters cannot be bound to it.

#### So in your case...

So you will need to provide another method overload that is a true zero-parameter, or wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
public void Test(Int32 a = 0) {}
public void Test() {}

Action d = Test;
```

Or:

```
Action d = () => Test();
```

Comment: To be fair, the language rules could have been written to cope with this - to allow a method group conversion that did the same thing as the lambda expression. But that's not the way the spec is written.

Answer (score 0):

When type checking with delegates, the compiler will apparently ignore the "optional"ness of optional arguments and think they are required.

You can declare your own delegate type to work around this:

```
public delegate void MyDel(int i = 1); // this 1 here can be any number. It does not seem to matter
//...
MyDel d = Test;
d();
```

Alternatively, you can just add a little `() =>` to call `Test` in a lambda:

```
Action d = () => Test();
```